# 3 white balls, 2 green and 1 red ball

Tags: probability

There are $3$ white, $2$ green, and $1$ red balls in a bag.

$2$ balls are drawn from the bag.

What is the probability of drawing $1$ white and $1$ green ball?

I've come up with the following:
Probability to draw a white ball, then green ball is
$\frac{3}{6} \times \frac{2}{5} = \frac{1}{5}$
Also, you can draw green then white, so
$\frac{2}{6} \times \frac{3}{5} = \frac{1}{5}$

The probability is $\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{5}=\frac{2}{5}$

I don't feel this is right, but the solution in my textbook says $\frac{2}{5}$.

Comment: Why do you think it is not right?

Comment: Are balls returned to the bag after each draw?

Comment: Math Lover - I don't think it is right, because I don't know why I'm summing the 2 probabilities. I feel like they are the same probability.

Comment: uriyaba - no, the balls are not returned to the bag

Comment: It is not. Consider this then - $\frac{3C1 \times 2C1}{6C2}$. Now are you convinced?

Comment: Math Lover - Can you give me an explanation of what the combinations mean. As I understand it. (Total numbers of combinations I can get 1 white in 3 whites * total number od combinations I can get 1 green in 2 greens) / total number of all combinations

Comment: I mean it is not wrong.

Comment: On the combinations, you are picking two balls - one white one green. So you pick $1$ out of $3$ white ($3C1$) and one out of $2$ green ($2C1$). The denominator has unrestricted ways to pick two balls out of six.

Comment: Math Lover - Great, thank you very much, I understood it better now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let P = The probability of drawing 1 white ball and 1 green ball **(in any order)**, it is, naturally, equal to the **sum of all possible ways you can draw these 2 balls**, which are:

Way 1: Drawing a green ball, then a white ball, for which, the probability is: $$P_1=\frac{3}{6}\times\frac{2}{5}=\frac{1}{5}$$

Way 2: Drawing a white ball, then a green ball, for which, the probability is: $$P_2=\frac{2}{6}\times\frac{3}{5}=\frac{1}{5}$$

And then: $$P=P_1+P_2=\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{5}=\frac{2}{5}$$

You could also compute P using the combinatoric function C, like so:

The number of ways to **pick 1 green ball from 3 total green balls** = $3C1$

The number of ways to **pick 1 white ball from 2 total white balls** = $2C1$

The number of ways to **pick 2 balls from 6 total balls** = $6C2$

Therefore:
$$P=\frac{3C1\times2C1}{6C2}=\frac{3\times2}{15}=\frac{2}{5}$$

Comment: Thank you, Math Lover, for reminding me about using the combinatoric function $C$!